# error codes for C functions under C++11?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I'm currently using a `C` library under C++11, the problem that I'm facing now and I never faced before, it's to handle errors and failures in a way that will be meaningful for the end user of my program.

At the moment in my C++ code there is something as `assert(foo())`, where `foo` is a function from this C library and it returns a `bool` which reflects the state of the operations, `true` everything is ok, `false` otherwise.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this, I would like to substitute the default message with some custom error code or a different string/message. Also note that I can't modify this library, so any possible solution needs to take this into account.

The are 2 main points that concern me:

1. `assert` is for when I compile my code in debug, I will basically never use `assert` in production or release mode, nor `assert` is intended to be used like I'm using it for the moment
2. a good portion of this functions is highly influenced by user input, so something that works at runtime is highly needed .

What should I do ? I basically have a C function that returns a `bool`, it doesn't uses any C or C++ specific error handling function or macro, I should wrap it inside a `try catch` ?

I'm also taking into account the fact that I would like to avoid calling `std::abort` and I would prefer to clean up everything in case of failure.

Comment: How do you handle errors in your C++ Code?

Comment: what do you want to happen if foo returns false?

Comment: Good error handling is very tricky in general. Consider reading this [series of posts](http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2012/01/sensible-error-handling-part-1.html). I consider it very helpful.

Comment: @sam all this functions are vital for the execution of my program, so if something fails I need to cleanup, exit and print a message according to what just failed and where.

Comment: @user2485710 Why would it be better then good old `assert`? If you can't handle something, don't handle it.

Comment: @cubuspl42 in C++ if an `assert` fails, it calls `std::abort`, plus if an assert fails there is no custom message or a good cleanup.

Comment: If you compile `assert(foo())` without assertions, `foo` will not be called.

Comment: followup on dorn's comment, `assert()` isn't the only thing that won't be used in "production" code with your `assert(foo());` expression. Neither will `foo()`. Seeing what [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) looks like will show you why.

Comment: @dornhege that's kinda what I was describing with my point `1` and point `2` in my "list". Certainly `assert` is compact and handy but it will not work out that well at runtime with user input.

Comment: You seem to have ignored TNAs question, so I will repeat it.  In the pure C++ portion of your code base, how do you handle errors and report to the user?  If there is no such, how do you prefer to do it at the company/personally?  There are so many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use C++ **exceptions**.

You can use some of the already defined standard C++ exception classes, like `std::runtime_error`, or you can define some custom exception class (derived from e.g. `std::runtime_error`).

e.g.

```
// FooWrapper.h  --  C++ wrapper around your "foo" library

#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>  // For std::runtime_error
#include "foo.h"      // The C library header

...

namespace Foo {  // Can wrap the raw C library nicely in a namespace


// Custom exception class for your "foo" errors.
class FooError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    explicit FooError(const std::string& errorMessage) 
        : std::runtime_error(errorMessage) { 

       // Can do additional initialization stuff, and pass
       // additional information regarding the particular "Foo" error,
       // e.g. as another constructor parameter.
       // ...

    }
};

... other stuff in the wrapping header ...

} // namespace Foo
```

Then, in your C++ code, you can `throw` the aforementioned exception when `foo()` function call fails:

```
if (! foo()) {
    throw Foo::FooError("Some information", ...some other error params... );
}
```

And you can `catch` that and try to recover or print a nice error message in the GUI part of your code, e.g.:

```
try {

     // ... do something ...

} catch( const Foo::FooError& fooError ) {

    // ... try to recover, or display the error message 
    // returned by fooError.what()
}
```

Note also that, since the `FooError` exception class is inserted into the standard C++ exception hierarchy (since it's derived from `std::runtime_error`), this custom exception can also be caught by C++ code already present in your code base, that tries to catch the more generic `std::runtime_error` or `std::exception` classes.

Comment: there isn't a construct or a way to make this less verbose ? I mean for 1 row of text where I call my function I should add like 4-5 rows of additional text for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you well. If you wrap the `foo()` call into some C++ function, then you just call this C++ function in your C++ code, and it's just one line of code (calling the C++ wrapper function). Then, in some part of your code, you can have the `try`/`catch` block, to catch the exception and react accordingly. You may want to read the [C++ FAQ on exceptions and error handling](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/exceptions.html).

Comment: The question could really not be answered in a general way I think.

Every application must be designed in a more or less consequent fashion for error handling. What is the sense of exceptions, if there is no really use case of catching them? If errors can be handled locally, why I should throw? If error could not be handled locally, how should the "higher level" part of the application know how to handle an error? Also assert is not really helpful. Why a application should stop only if a file is not existing?

Answer (score 1):

Put all entry points to the library in your code within `try`/`catch` blocks as you suggested. Then the quickest and simplest solution is

```
if (!foo())
    throw std::runtime_error("foo(): returned false");
```

as needed. You can create your own exception class (possibly but not necessarily derived from `std::exception` when you decide you need more structured behavior, e.g. behavior which depends on exactly which function fails.  In the simple case you would just have

```
try
{
   ... //The if/throw test will typically not occur here, but deeper within the call stack.
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
   std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
   //do cleanup
}
```

or something like that.  Edit: As @TNA emphasizes, you put the try/catch block at the point in the code where you are able to handle the error.  The `if`/`throw` tests can occur anywhere.

Comment: If you can handle all errors locally, what's the point of using exeptions at all? Why not dirctly do something like `if (!foo()) handleError();` if that's possible.

Comment: I don't understand, my functions are `C` functions, they don't throw anything in any case.

Comment: @TNA There is no reason to assume the `foo()` test will happen directly within the try block.  There could be many layers of function call in between, and the ability of C++ exceptions to unroll the stack is one of their key advantages.  Compare to C where you're forced to pass a return code from function to function.

Comment: @user2485710 Yes so why make them throw as Matt Phillips suggested unless you want to use non-local error handling.

Comment: @user2485710 `throw` is a C++ construct.  You are calling the C functions from within C++ code right?  So it is this code which will test and `throw`.

Comment: that's it ? an `if` inside a `try` ? I can write a `noexcept` constructor in C++11 and I need to be so verbose to handle 1 single function call ?

Comment: @Matt Phillips: That's right. I thought by
"Put all entry points to the library in your code within try/catch blocks" means to wrap all calls in try/catch blocks. It only makes sense to use try/catch blocks at the point where you can handle that error. If you can't hanle it at all, just let the exeption terminate you program is a good option too.

Comment: @TNA I agree completely, just wrapping if/throw statements in a try/catch block is a waste, I will edit my answer shortly to clarify that this is not what I meant.

Comment: @user2485710 See my edit, this should clarify the intended use of the C++ exception structure.

Answer (score 0):

If macro and go to statement can be considered, I think this can be an alternative:

```
#define CHECK (fn) if (!fn) \
{ \
// Set the valid error msg somewhere  that can be retrieved later on..
 goto QUIT; \
} \

// Usage
AnyObject Afnc()
{

AnyObject anyObj;

CHECK(foo())


QUIT: 
 return anyObj;
```

}